# Simulate a Keystroke in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

I want to be able to simulate a keystroke from my firefox-addon and at the moment I'm not being able to do that.

I found this post [Why simulation of Left Arrow + Shift keys doesnt work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244932/why-simulation-of-left-arrow-shift-keys-doesnt-work-in-firefox) and my code is almost the same, but it only does the focus part, not the dispatchEvent. Any idea why this could be happening?

Here is the code:

```
objTag.focus();
var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
e.initKeyEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 35, 0);
objTag.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: You are correctly sending a`keydown` event (End key) to some element. Maybe you should explain what effect you expect to see? Also, if `objTag` is indeed an object (meaning Flash or something like this) - plugins have their own event processing that is independent of the browser, they will not receive events generated by the browser.

Comment: My add-on is going to put some extra text at the end of a textarea. I wanted to simulate the END key and then a SPACE key. The objtag is the textarea element. It is doing the focus, but then it doesn't go to the end of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct but the `<textarea>` element reacts to `keypress` events, not `keydown`.

Anyway, why so complicated? You can just set `input.value` and then use [`input.setSelectionRange()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.setSelectionRange) to move the cursor appropriately. If you want to add something to the end of the current line you would do it like this:

```js
var position = objTag.selectionStart;
var lineEnd = objTag.value.indexOf("\n", position);
if (lineEnd < 0) // No more line breaks
  lineEnd = objTag.value.length;

var textToAdd = "foo";
objTag.value = objTag.value.substr(0, lineEnd) + textToAdd + objTag.value.substr(lineEnd);
objTag.setSelectionRange(lineEnd + textToAdd.length, lineEnd + textToAdd.length);
objTag.focus();
```

Adding to the end of the text is even simpler:

```js
var textToAdd = "foo";
objTag.value += textToAdd;
objTag.setSelectionRange(objTag.value.length, objTag.value.length);
objTag.focus();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your responses. I tried this but it doesn't do exactly what i wanted. Maybe i could have explained myself better. I will update the question with a little more information

Comment: Actually, the 'keypress' part worked well at doing the keystroke, but it still doesn't solve all my problem, since it doesn't have the exact effect i get when i press the same key on the keyboard. The site has a input element that triggers a auto-complete list when i press space,backspace,end, etc. but i can't replicate that behavior with this solution.

Comment: @fsilva: Then you probably want to send `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup` for each key - that's the way to simulate user input properly.

Comment: That did it! Thank you @Wladimir :). Is there a reason for the tab key not work in the same way? Maybe the content of the autosuggestions is taking more time to load and i trigger it before it loads completely.